# 01722. 00000 - "invalid number" / how to update row correctly?

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have a table **foo** with colum **C1** of type **smallint**. this table contains values **1** and **2** for **C1**

Now I have changed the type of **C1 from smallint to VARCHAR2**.

I have to update the table with the following logic:

**for every row where C1 = 1 C1 should be now A**

**for every row where C1 = 2  C1 should be now B**

I use the following statement to update:

```
update foo 
SET C1 = 'A' 
WHERE C1 =0; 

update foo 
SET C1 = 'B' 
WHERE C1 =1; 

commit;
```

now I get the following error:

1722. 00000 -  "invalid number"

How to update correctly? I use oracle 12C database

Comment: Sounds like your column still expects a smallint. Your guess update should go from string to string, so `SET C1 = 'A' WHERE C1 = '0'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you change the value to a string, you should use strings for the comparison.  So try this version:

```
update foo 
SET C1 = 'A' 
WHERE C1 = '0'; 

update foo 
SET C1 = 'B' 
WHERE C1 = '1'; 

commit;
```

I think the `where` clause is causing the error, because the `'A'` values from the first update cannot be converted to a number.

Alternatively, you could do:

```
update foo
    set c1 = (case when c1 = '0' then 'A' else 'B' end)
    where c1 in ('0', '1');

commit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you first have to change your column type.
If you done it already, that its probably because of the lack of quotes `'` , strings should be wrapped with single quote marks :

```
ALTER TABLE foo 
  MODIFY C1 varchar2(2);

update foo 
SET C1 = CASE WHEN C1 = '0' THEN 'A' 
              WHEN C1 = '1' THEN 'B'
         END
```

As you see, I combined your two queries into one using `CASE EXPRESSION` , no need for two different updates. If more then two options of `C1` is possible, use a `WHERE` clause :

```
update foo 
SET C1 = CASE WHEN C1 = '0' THEN 'A' 
              WHEN C1 = '1' THEN 'B'
         END
WHERE C1 IN('0','1')
```